# Are all Socket G2 processors interchangeable?

Tags: laptop, cpu

I've got an HP probook 4540s and I'm looking at upgrades, but I want to know what my options are. Will I be able to use any Socket G2 processor, or am I limited to the ones the laptop ships with?

Comment: My research indicates that the HP Probook 4540 CPU is soldered onto the motherboard.

Comment: I'm looking at my motherboard as we speak, definitely not soldered in.

Comment: The BIOS is often a limiter, so check what it can support.

Answer (score 2):

More or less. I remember how surprised I was to learn that laptops now have removable/upgradable processors. I even had a D830 upgraded to a T9550, and note that it never came stock with that high end a processor in any configuration as far as I've been able to find.

Things to confirm compatibility with:

**Hardware** (same socket = physically will fit = theoretically should be possible to make compatible)

**Chipset** (Did that chipset ever come with the processor you have in mind?)

**Power Req's** (Higher wattage processor? Find out the highest wattage config your laptop came with stock, and see the TDP of that processor to give you an idea. Not what you want to see? Monitor your processor temps under heavy usage as-is, and see if it's significantly below your limits. If so, you may have enough head room to put in a hotter cpu.)

**Bios** (update to the latest, and again, did this processor ever come stock with this computer? If it didn't you're gambling a bit--see if someone else has tried before you. Apparently if the bios doesn't recognize the processor, you're screwed.)

Here's a video of someone doing so with what I believe should be a G1 socket processor. He upgrades to a gen 2 quad core i7. **Note that turbo boost didn't work for him**, but that otherwise, everything went well.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmehOINmxUE

Answer (score 0):

Even if the processor was not soldered to the mainboard, an upgrade processor would probably let the temperature raise higher than before when under load. To prevent damage, you'd need to also upgrade the cooling system.

While you can upgrade the CPU fan in a normal (Desktop, Tower) computer more or less easily, this is almost impossible to do in a notebook.

Comment: Yeah, it's not soldered in. Furthermore, I have upgraded laptop processors before and I know about proper heat management. I was asking if G2 processors are intercompatible.

Comment: @Waago - The speciciations are on Intel's website.  You have not provided enough information and from what I can tell, when I found HP 4540's they had BGA CPUs.

Comment: I'm looking at it now. If I felt like repasting it, I would gladly pop it out. The question is relatively straightforward; if I have a Pentium B980, can I replace it with a i7 3940xm? They're both the same socket.